# How do you multiply hex numbers to implement the inverse MixColumns from the AES?

Tags: c++, math, encryption, aes

I am writing the AES in c++, and am having problems with the inverse Mixcolumns function. I must multiply an array with a matrix doing a dot product essentially. I solved the encryption MixColumns using this resource [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/how-to-solve-mixcolumns), and tried to implement the Inverse function using this resource [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/how-does-one-implement-the-inverse-of-aes-mixcolumns). I am using the solution for multiplying by 2 from the first resource, which looks like this:

- (d4×02) is d4<<1, XORed with 1b (because the high bit of d4 is set)

So using the second resource, I am implementing multiplying by 9, 11, 13, 14 by

- x×9=(((x×2)×2)×2)+x
- x×11=((((x×2)×2)+x)×2)+x
- x×13=((((x×2)+x)×2)×2)+x
- x×14=((((x×2)+x)×2)+x)×2

This is my function, that I am made to try to implement the inverse MixColumns:

```
void InvMixColumns(unsigned char plainText[4][4])
{

    unsigned char temp[4] = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 };

    unsigned char newState[4][4] = { {0,0,0,0},
                                     {0,0,0,0},
                                     {0,0,0,0},
                                     {0,0,0,0} };

    int rijndaelMatric[4][4] = { {14,11,13,9},
                                 {9,14,11,13},
                                 {13,9,14,11},
                                 {11,13,9,14} };

    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = 0x00;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                unsigned char constant = 0x00;
                switch (rijndaelMatric[z][j])
                {
                case 9:
                    // Check if highest bit is 1.
                    if ((plainText[j][y] & 0x80) == 0x80)
                        constant = 0x1B;

                    temp[j] = ((((((plainText[j][y] << 1) ^ constant) << 1) ^ constant) << 1) ^ constant) ^ plainText[j][y];
                    break;
                case 11:
                    // Check if highest bit is 1.
                    if ((plainText[j][y] & 0x80) == 0x80)
                        constant = 0x1B;

                    temp[j] = (((((((plainText[j][y] << 1) ^ constant) << 1) ^ constant) ^ plainText[j][y]) << 1) ^ constant) ^ plainText[j][y];
                    break;
                case 13:
                    // Check if highest bit is 1.
                    if ((plainText[j][y] & 0x80) == 0x80)
                        constant = 0x1B;

                    temp[j] = (((((((plainText[j][y] << 1) ^ constant) ^ plainText[j][y]) << 1) ^ constant) << 1) ^ constant) ^ plainText[j][y];
                    break;
                case 14:
                    // Check if highest bit is 1.
                    if ((plainText[j][y] & 0x80) == 0x80)
                        constant = 0x1B;

                    temp[j] = (((((((plainText[j][y] << 1) ^ constant) ^ plainText[j][y]) << 1) ^ constant) ^ plainText[j][y]) << 1) ^ constant;
                    break;
                }

            }
            newState[x][y] = int(temp[0]) ^ int(temp[1]) ^ int(temp[2]) ^ int(temp[3]);
            z++;
        }

    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
        {
            plainText[x][y] = newState[x][y];
        }
    }

}
```

This is an example of one of the states that will be ran through the function:

| be | ae | 65 | 1a |

| 4e | 78 | ac | d7 |

| c3 | 25 | 94 | 27 |

| c1 | 76 | 88 | 64 |

Should Be:

| 89 | c2 | 22 | fd |

| 66 | 3b | 6b | 44 |

| 0b | 58 | 62 | c7 |

| 16 | 24 | fe | f0 |

But I get:

| 89 | c2 | 0f | cb |

| 4b | 16 | 70 | 44 |

| 10 | 43 | 54 | ea |

| 20 | 12 | fe | eb |

Am I missing something? Am I looking over something? The only thing that changed from the normal MixColumns and the inverse function above is the multiplication part in the sswitch, so it has to be something with the implementatin, but I can't see what.

If you want to see all the code/ want to run it you can [here](https://github.com/HLRichardson-Git/AES/blob/main/AES.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about intermediate multiplications.  You must check before each multiplication if the result will overflow and xor with 0x1B accordingly.

In other words, your inner switch() should look more like this (I've shortened variable names for readability:

```
unsigned char x = plainText[j][y];
unsigned char y = 0;
switch (rijndaelMatric[z][j]) {
    case 9:
        y = (x << 1) ^ ((x & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 2
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 4
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 8
        y ^= x;                                    // x 9
        temp[j] = y;
        break;
    case 11:
        y = (x << 1) ^ ((x & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 2
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 4
        y ^= x;                                    // x 5
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 10
        y ^= x;                                    // x 11
        temp[j] = y;
        break;
    case 13:
        y = (x << 1) ^ ((x & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 2
        y ^= x;                                    // x 3
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 6
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 12
        y ^= x;                                    // x 13
        temp[j] = y;
        break;
    case 14:
        // Check if highest bit is 1.
        y = (x << 1) ^ ((x & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 2
        y ^= x;                                    // x 3
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 6
        y ^= x;                                    // x 7
        y = (y << 1) ^ ((y & 0x80) ? 0x1B : 0x00); // x 14

        temp[j] = y;
        break;
}
```

You can check the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/hccnvcqex